# Overriden function fails to compile when I add an additional parameter to the override

Tags: scala, overriding, currying

I have a function with an override that fails when I add an additional parameter to the override:

This compiles:

```
object Test {
    def foo[T](x: Boolean)(y: Boolean): Boolean = x == y

    def bar[T](y: String, x:  T => Boolean)(z: => T) {}

    def bar[T](x: String)(z: => T) {}

    bar("qwer", foo(false)) {
      true
    }

    bar("qwer") {
      true
    }
}
```

But if I add a second parameter to the second bar method:

```
def bar[T](x: String, y: Int)(z: => T) {}

bar("qwer", foo(false)) {
  true
}

bar("qwer", 123) {
  true
}
```

Then the program doesn't compile with the error:

```
error: missing arguments for method foo in object Test;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a 
partially applied function
```

My question is: Why does "inference" (not sure if that's the correct terminology) of the curried function work when the second bar method has one parameter but stop working when a second parameter is added?

This is with Scala version 2.10.3.